# How can I set the seed command in R when simulating data many times?

Tags: r, simulation

The following is a function to simulate data :

```
    library(mvtnorm)

    simu <- function(J,n_j,g00,g10,g01,g11,s2_0,s2_1,s01){
        N = sum(rep(n_j,J))  

        x = rnorm(N)        
        z = rnorm(J)         

        mu <- c(0,0)
        sig <- matrix(c(s2_0,s01,s01,s2_1),ncol=2)
        u   <- rmvnorm(J,mean=mu,sigma=sig)

        pi_0 <- g00 + g01*z + u[,1]
        pi_1 <- g10 + g11*z + u[,2]

        eta <- rep(pi_0,each=n_j) + (rep(pi_1,each=n_j))*x
        p = exp(eta)/(1+exp(eta))

        y <- rbinom(N,1,p)
       data <- data.frame(Y=y,X=x,Z=rep(z,each=n_j),cluster=rep(1:J,each=n_j))

       return(data)
  } # end function simu

  a=replicate(5,simu(30,5,-1,.3,.3,.3,.13,1,0)
```

I want to replicate the function `simu` 1000 times for various combination of parameter values which take lengthy processing time . Each time I have to compute many summary measures from the simulated data . But it is not possible in one session . So I need to set the seed command so that `a=replicate(5,simu(30,5,-1,.3,.3,.3,.13,1,0))` will produce same data sets in each session .

How can I do that ?

I have thought of something like that :

```
for (i in 1:5){
    set.seed(i)
    a[i]=simu(30,5,-1,.3,.3,.3,.13,1,0))
 }
```

But it's not working . It would be better if I can set the `seed` command somewhere else without using the `for loop` command . Is it possible ?

Thanks ! Regards .

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did you create `a` before assigning the function result to it?

Comment: @Molx yes . I wrote `a = NULL` .

Comment: And why didn't it work?

Comment: @Molx It gives the `Warning messages:
1: In a[i] = simu(30, 5, -1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.13, 1, 0) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In a[i] = simu(30, 5, -1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.13, 1, 0) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> 
`

Comment: Try `a[[i]]` instead. You're adding a list element, you should use `[[`, otherwise it will try to add the data frame in place of a one-length vector element.

Comment: Oh , it is working when I set the seed command before `replicate` .

Comment: @Molx Yes you're right . I should use a[[i]] . ThanKs a lot .

Comment: Actually, I just realized that what you're doing is probably unecessary. If you're going to set the same seeds multiple times, you can do it only once and all random results after it will always be the same, no matter how many they are.

Comment: `set.seed(i)` inside a `for` loop is unnecessary. Pick a number and `set.seed(47)` (or whatever number you choose) once, before the for loop.

Comment: It's better if you set the seed only once, at the beginning of your code. Setting the seed too often is a bad idea, as explained in the answer to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86285/random-number-set-seedn-in-r) post.